# Single plot multiple lines passing an array of colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plotting two lines with a single `plot` command should not be easy?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([[1,2],[5,6]], c=['k','g'])

ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument
```

I just need two lines, one is black and the other green. What is going on here?

Comment: as stated in the docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html): "If you make multiple lines with one plot command, the kwargs apply to all those lines..." so the way bellow by @mauve is the way to go

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro so with multiple lines you just have to write a loop? No way of inputting a color array?

Comment: It's what the docs says,

Comment: but you can use the workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348687/1207193 if you want very much one line command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 lines, not 2 points, to plot 2 lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x1, y1,  c = 'k')
plt.plot(x2, y2,  c = 'g') #x1, y1, x2, y2 should be multiple points
```

Comment: So there is no one-liner to plot pairs of points and giving a list of colors for each?

Comment: You are wrong man! Surely you can plot multiple lines at once, look the picture https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348687/1207193

Comment: But to plot lines, you definitely need data...that is lines. A single point is not a line.

Comment: @mauve I think you didn't get yet. The OP question plots two lines. Every line is made by two points. And as you can see bellow the sintax for plotting is correct, those are four points (2 lines), x coordinate is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that very much...

You can control the colors that will be cycled through using `cycler`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', ['black', 'green']))

ax.plot([[1,2],[5,6]])
```

[image]